# What are the meaning of keys in OVPN file?

Tags: openvpn, ssl, pfsense

I have ovpn file, which allows me to connect to remote server successfully from desktop OpenVPN GUI. Now I want to copy content of this file to OpenVPN client of pfSense. The problem is that fields are not 1:1 correspondent.

I have the following in OVPN file

```
<key> BEGIN PRIVATE KEY ...

<cert> BEGIN CERTIFICATE ...

<ca> BEGIN CERTIFICATE

<tls-ath> BEGIN OpenVPN Static Key V1
```

What are these fields?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Static Key V1`.  The Private key and Certificate are part of your client's authentication. When you connect to an openvpn server it is common for your client to have it's own certificate and private key to authenticate itself with the server.  You may also need to provide a username and password, but the server will not even let you try to login if the certificate isn't correct.  The certificate must be valid (issued by the right CA) and the private key must be the matching key for that certificate.  (Assuming that's how it's been configured).

Answer (score 1):

Some of the OpenVPN configuration options can either reference a file or you can embed the PEM/base64 data directly in the configuration file.

https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-4/#inline-file-support

The options are often `--foo` on the command line. `foo <file>` in the config file. Or `<foo>...</foo>` if inlined in the config file. They're all referring to the same config options.

Embedding directly in the configuration file makes them more portable because it can be a completely standalone setup.